# Graphing a function of 4 variables

Tags: python, animation, plot, graphics, 3d

I want to graph a function of 4 variables, I am thinking we can plot the first three variables in space, using a color code, then make the colors change as by the 4th variable which is time.

The graph will be then an animation of the space. At each time we can see the colors in the space, each pixel will have a color that indicate the value of the function at that point (x, y, z)

Any suggestions? Maybe in python or matlab?

Answer (score 0):

You could try python and [meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio#readme) to export the data to vtk quad mesh and do the rest in ParaView. I thing you have to make a separate file for each time point with numbering in the filename to be recognised as a time dependent data.